# Filter in template to arrange data specifically in django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

How can I use a filter in my template to put the values in a row where the key matches.

So for example all values in Inner OD key  row 1 should have values for that key 
then in row two the should have all values of Outter OD key for row 2 values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Here is my view.py

```
@login_required 
def shipping(request, id): 
  sheet_data = Sheet.objects.get(pk=id) 
  work_order = sheet_data.work_order 
  customer_data = Customer.objects.get(id=sheet_data.customer_id) 
  customer_name = customer_data.customer_name 
  title_head = 'Shipping-%s' % sheet_data.work_order 
  complete_data = Sheet.objects.raw("""select s.id, d.id d_id, s.work_order, d.target, i.reading, d.description, i.serial_number from app_sheet s left join app_dimension d on s.id = d.sheet_id 
  left join app_inspection_vals i on d.id = i.dimension_id""") 

  for c_d in complete_data: 
    dim_description = Dimension.objects.filter(sheet_id=c_d.id).values_list('description', flat=True).distinct() 

    dim_id = Dimension.objects.filter(sheet_id=c_d.id)[:1] 
    for d_i in dim_id: 
      dim_data = Inspection_vals.objects.filter(dimension_id=d_i.id) 
      reading_data = Inspection_vals.objects.filter(dimension_id=d_i.id)       

  key_list = [] 
  vals_list = [] 

  for xr in complete_data: 

    key_list.append(xr.description) 
    vals_list.append(xr.reading) 

    #print reading_desc 
    sample_size = dim_data   
  res = {} 
  for i in range(len(key_list)): 
    if key_list[i] in res: 
      res[key_list[i]].append(vals_list[i]) 
    else: 
      res[key_list[i]]=[vals_list[i]] 

  reading_desc = res 

  return render(request, 'app/shipping.html', 
  { 
     'work_order': work_order, 
     'sample_size': sample_size, 
     'customer_name': customer_name, 
     'title': title_head, 
     'complete_data': complete_data, 
     'dim_description': dim_description, 
     'reading_desc': reading_desc, 
  })
```

here is the output of reading_desc that correctly uses the correct key and values for each.

```
    {u'Inner OD': [2, None, None, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 7, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, None, 3, 4, 6], u'Outter OD': [3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6, 5, 2, 3]}
```

Here is my template shipping.html

```
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="row"> 
      <div> 
        <table > 
          <thead> 
          <tr> 
            <th>Serial Number</th> 
            {% for ss in sample_size %} 
               <th>{{ ss.serial_number }}</th> 
            {% endfor %} 
          </tr> 
          </thead> 
          <tbody> 
             {% for desc in dim_description.all %} 
             <tr> 
                <th> {{ desc }}</th> 
                {% for r_c in reading_desc %} 
                  <td class="{% cycle r_c, r_c %}"> {{ r_c }} </td> 
                {% endfor %}                 
             {% endfor %} 
             </tr> 
          </tbody> 
        </table> 
     </div>       
  </div> 
</div>
```

Here is what I would like it to look like

[image: Filter]

Comment: So you are asking how to iterate over a dictionary and show the key and values in a table format?

Comment: Basically yes @MichaelPlatt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright then here we go.  This is how you loop over a dictionary in an html page using Django:

```
<tbody> 
    <tr> 
    {% for desc in dim_description.all %} 
        <th> {{ desc }}</th>  
    {% endfor %} 
    </tr>
    {% for key, values in reading_desc.items %} 
    <tr>
        <td class="some_class_here"> {{ key }} </td> 
        {% for v in values %}
        <td class="some_class_here">{{ v }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    <tr>
    {% endfor %}                 
</tbody>
```

This should be enough to get you going.  There's a few things happening here.  First, in the first loop that iterates over the dim_description list, we are adding a single row with a number of `<th>` tags to display the headers (in your case 1-24).  Then in the second loop we are looping over the dictionary.  We start with displaying the key (Inner OD for the first iteration), then we have to loop over all the values for each key (the inner for loop in the second for loop in the page) and it should display what you want.  This may not be the full answer but it should give you the bones enough to tackle your problem.